# Selecting files from multiple directories for R input

Tags: r

I have files `a.ext`,`b.ext`,`c.ext` to select from directory `/mypath1` and `d.ext`,`e.ext`,`f.ext` from directory `/mypath2`. How do I select those files from two(or even more) directories and store those file names in an object?

tried something like this, but did not work here: `(my.dir <- "mypath1"|"mypath2")`.

```
my.dir <- "mypath1"|"mypath2"
my.dir
all.files<-list.files(my.dir)
```

Comment: `lapply(c("mypath1", "mypath2"), list.files)` maybe?  Are you just trying to get the file names themselves?

Comment: I am trying to work on those files looping over one after another.

Answer (score 2):

Learn to move around in different directories. Say there is a directory "parent directory" that has 2 folders in it, and you want to select files from these 2 folders:

```
my.dir <- setwd("parent directory")
setwd("./path1")
# get files
setwd('../')
setwd("./path2")
# get files
```

./ goes down from the current directory and ../ goes up.

Answer (score 1):

Just do list.files twice, and make use of the pattern argument:

```
list.files(list.files(".",pattern="mypath1|mypath2"))
```

Comment: Gives me this error : Error in "/media/BAM" |  : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

Comment: you probably aren't using a valid regex. E.g., you might need to escape special characters.